# Using LINQ, how do I look at List that is contained in another object/List?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have IEnumOfFood that contains a food object that lists out each ingredient. So something like IEnumOfFood[0] would be {'Celery', 'Onion', 'Chicken', [Stock]}. In this case, [Stock] is another IEnumerable. I'm trying to get each element in IEnumOfFood where Stock.Herb == "Bay Leaf".
It seems that no matter how I try and reword the LINQ query it always has some sort of error. Currently I have this:

```
IEnumOfFood= IEnumFoodItems.Select(x => x.Select(
y => y.Stock.Where(
y => y.Herb == "BayLeaf")));
```

Which throws a 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type'.
This is just one of the many ways I've tried to get an element of IEnumOfFood where the Stock Enum has herb as 'Bay Leaf', I'm not saying this is what should work.

Comment: Can you post the real code pls? {'Celery', 'Onion', 'Chicken', [Stock]} doesn' t look like a valid data for c#

Comment: You can't re-use the variable name  `y` in a scope where it's already been defined. Change the last `y` to some other name.

Comment: @Serge That's not really the important part of it. That's just a rough idea of what the object would sorta look like. I'm really just focused on the getting a Food object based on an element within the Stock object.

Comment: @ScottHannen Sorry I forgot to change that but I still get the same error as above.

Comment: @CoolGuyJones If it is not important, you  can find tons  different examples how to query children . You don' t need one more example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tryed:

```
IEnumFoodItems.Where(x => x.Any(s => s.Stock.Any(h => h.Herb == "BayLeaf")))
```

Comment: Hey Thank you, that seems to have worked! I Appreciate it.